# Thread within a Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-sleep

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {
    private Intent myintent;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        myintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        splashScreen(1000); }

    public void splashScreen (final int x)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(x);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startActivity(myintent);
                finish();
            }
        }).run();
    }

}
```

There's the code, and here is the problem : the SplashScreen do not get the content view of the splash XML layout file... Now, I have my suspicions that it is a thread problem and that somehow the thread is executed before the setContentView method although that method is located before the run method of the Thread in code, so it's illogical that I'm thinking this way but I'm like running out of reasons for this Splash Screen not to work

Comment: by using `run()` you are still blocking the UI Thread. use `.start()` instead. Also keep in mind that using a Thread isn't that great for a splash screen, you can also try using a Handler. But first assess if a splash is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! :) can you tell me the difference between run and start

Comment: calling `run()` is the direct method call. using `.start()` actually does the execution in `run()` run in a separate Thread.

Comment: Again thanks a lot A--C Thank you very much !!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `thread.run()` to `thread.start()`: http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article1131.html

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(x);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
        }
    }).start();
```

A better way to implement Splash:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    myintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Yes that is true
Thank you and A--C already told me that but I'm going to select your answer since (s)he didn't putt it in answer but in a comment
Again thank you for answering

Answer (score 4):

```
    package com.echo.myatlsnookpaid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3500);
//                  sleep(100);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openMain = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(openMain);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

and in your manifest, give the

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

filter to he splashactivity.

Comment: Thanks the manifest is already something like that though, and yeah all I needed to do is replace the run method with start

Comment: Ah. i misread your example code in the beginning. yes, start is all you needed to change.